# Using Null Analysis annotations in Java8

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, java-8

In Java, I use the 'null analysis' using annotations. I don't use Eclipse's default annotations and I have defined my owns.

For each package, I used to add a global `NonNullByDefault` annotation in the `package-info.java` file.

With Java version <= Java7, the code below has no problem, everything works fine.

```
@my.package.annotations.NonNullByDefault
package my.foo.package;
```

But when I set Eclipse to be Java8 compliant (the only JDK installed on my system is Java8), then an error occurs:

> A default nullness annotation has not been specified for the package my.foo.package   - Java Problem

My annotation is declared in the following way:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.PACKAGE, ElementType.TYPE, 
          ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR })
public @interface NonNullByDefault { 
    // marker annotation
}
```

What's new in Java8 about that? Can someone explain me the good way to use my annotations?

Comment: Please provide a full definition of your `NonNullByDefault` annotation.

Comment: The annotation is just used to check if it's present or not. There is no code in.

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.PACKAGE, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR })
public @interface NonNullByDefault
{
 // marker annotation
}

And it's works fine using the Java7 compliance

Answer (score 1):

JDT's own annotations have significantly changed between versions 1.x and 2.x of org.eclipse.jdt.annotation. To fully leverage the greater precision of type annotations in Java 8, `@NonNullByDefault` now has an attribute of type `DefaultLocation[]`, specifying where exactly the default should apply.

Rebuilding your own annotations with the same level of details and making JDT understand your own annotations will be cumbersome.

Still, an attribute-less `@NonNullByDefault` should be understood in the "default" way (see the default value of `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault.value`). Apparently there's [a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470691) in the evaluation of such custom annotations in Java 8 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following:

1. Put a file name `package-info.java` into each of your Java packages
2. Enter the following in the file:

   `@NonNullByDefault
       package your.package;
       import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;`

This will specify that you don't want to accept null anywhere for any argument and you will also not be putting loads of `@NonNull` in the code. You may get a warning like `A default nullness annotation has not been specified for the package my.foo.package` if you create a new package but forget to copy the file.

Comment: That is exactly what I am already doing. I juste use my own annotation instead of org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault. My code has no problem using the Java7 compliance.

Comment: Okay. It should be working because when I had similar problem this was what I did and it worked for me. Anyways then I may not find any other problem.